# No result displaying firebase datas

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner in Javascript and Ionic, and I try to get my head around simply displaying datas from the database.

However I can't check my console while doing this for various reasons of device.

Anyway, here is the code I use to display the "description" of a user :

```
// Get a database reference to our posts
var descriptionRef = new Firebase("https://swapizapplication.firebaseio.com/accounts/-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7");
// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
descriptionRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
var descriptionSnapshot = snapshot.child("displayDescription");
var description = descriptionSnapshot.val();
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

All I want is that when I write **{{description}}** on a html page linked to the controller that has that code, it displays the data of database for the user "-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7" at "displayDescription" (the name of one of the field in that user's database)

However it doesn't display the data. The page shows up, no particular error showing up, but the data just doesn't show up.

Here is how I made my controller (full view) :

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
      //Get logged in user credentials.
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var name, email, photoUrl, provider;


            console.log("User: " + JSON.stringify(user));
      if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        provider = user.provider;
        description = user.displayDescription

      }

      //Set Profile Image.
      $scope.profileImage = photoUrl;
      //Set Profile Name.
      $scope.profileName = name;
      //Set Profile email.
        profileEmail = email;
            //Set provider.
            provider = provider;

// Get a database reference to our posts
var descriptionRef = new Firebase("https://swapizapplication.firebaseio.com/accounts/-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7");
// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
descriptionRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
var descriptionSnapshot = snapshot.child("displayDescription");
var description = descriptionSnapshot.val();
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
    });
  });
```

Any idea to help a NOOB ? :p

EDIT : Add the JSON of my database :

```
{
  "-KOjv0LDdoWrc3uApvPi" : {
    "dateCreated" : "Tue Aug 09 2016 11:29:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "email" : "bla@blabla.net",
    "provider" : "Facebook",
    "userId" : "FMXlUQZth5aehQLT2TKZZJZdJBh2"
  },
  "-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7" : {
    "dateCreated" : "Tue Aug 09 2016 16:16:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "displayDescription" : "no description",
    "email" : "blibli@blibli.com",
    "provider" : "Facebook",
    "userId" : "F9Z7YhSlmAQqOH5FVjBSV2CkYZG3"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2 :

I considered going for another solution, it still doesn't want to work !

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    //Get logged in user credentials.
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name, email, photoUrl, provider, description;

    console.log("User: " + JSON.stringify(user));
    if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        provider = user.provider;
    }

    //Set Profile Image.
    $scope.profileImage = photoUrl;
    //Set Profile Name.
    $scope.profileName = name;
    //Set Profile email.
    $scope.profileEmail = email;
    //Set provider.
    $scope.provider = provider;

        var descriptionRef = firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + user + '/displayDescription/' );
        descriptionRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        description = snapshot.val();
        $scope.description = description;
        $scope.$apply();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the main problem here, you're not exposing 'description' in the $scope, so the HTML template doesn't know that 'description' exists. So by calling `{{description}}`, you're probably getting an `undefined`, and that's why it isn't printing anything.

Then, referring to firebase. The statement `firebase.auth().currentUser` returns a `firebase.User` or `null` depending on whether you're logged in or not. A `firebase.User` does not contain a definition for `provider`. Instead, try using `providerId` or `providerData`. Also, a `firebase.User` neither contains a definition for `displayDescription`. That's an arbitrary key you defined in the user data as for `/accounts/-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7/displayDescription`.

If I'm not mistaken this should solve the problem:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    //Get logged in user credentials.
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name, email, photoUrl, provider, description;


    console.log("User: " + JSON.stringify(user));
    if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        provider = user.providerId;
    }

    //Set Profile Image.
    $scope.profileImage = photoUrl;
    //Set Profile Name.
    $scope.profileName = name;
    //Set Profile email.
    $scope.profileEmail = email;
    //Set provider.
    $scope.provider = provider;

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var descriptionRef = new Firebase("https://swapizapplication.firebaseio.com/accounts/-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7");
    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    descriptionRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var descriptionSnapshot = snapshot.child("displayDescription");
        description = descriptionSnapshot.val();
        $scope.description = description;
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello ! First of all thank you for taking the time to answer me and to make my code more presentable ! I really appreciate it : I am messy !
However, the result is the same... Nothing appears... It is hard to tell what could be the error...

Comment: Little EDIT : I added the JSON structure of my database in case it is not clear how it is made

Comment: There could be several things then. Maybe database security rules. Or the `.on('value', ...)` not getting invoked. Since you can't use the console to get feedback I suggest you to use an HTLM tag to do so. Something like this: `<div>{{ output }}</div>`  and exposing `$scope.output` in the controller should do the work. Just by appending data to your `$scope.output` you can get that precious feedback.

Comment: Well thank you for your help, none of this worked either :(

Comment: my rules : {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "accounts": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      ".indexOn": ["userId", "email"]
    }
  }
}